# No Typescript in VS2013 update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I installed VS2013 update 2 and now I have no typescript in VS anymore.

There is no editor colorization for typescript files and files are not compiled to js. There are also no options. I did uninstall and reinstall VS2013 update 2.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling TypeScript?

Comment: How? There is only a package for 2012. I reinstalled this without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall in this order:

- Typescript
- Visual Studio 2013

Install in this order:

- VS2013
- VS2013 Update 2

solved the issues for me now